# I want to run only my production stage on release pipeline when built is run of production. Same with development too

Tags: azure, devops, pipeline, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

run only my production stage on release pipeline when built is run of production not other stages. Same with development when i run built pipeline of dev only dev stage should run on release pipeline.

Same with development when i run built pipeline of dev only dev stage should run on release pipeline.

Comment: Hi, may i know if there's any update? Please follow my reply below for a check, let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

For **Classic** release pipeline, it has [trigger settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops) which doesn't allow you to specify the condition to run the target stage.

As an workaround, you can set the condition on `job` under the stage, steps as below:

1. I have release pipelines as below: test, dev, prod stages.
   [image]
2. Install extension [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CFIA-ACIA.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline), it can be used to trigger the release pipeline. Note: although it has stage setting to specify target release stage but it's not working properly.
3. In your **build pipeline**, invoke the above task, choose target release, set the release variable json as `{'RunStage' : 'dev'}` (dev is the target stage in this sample).

[image]

4. In **release** pipeline, add variable `RunStage`, set it as `release` scope, and settable during release.
   [image]
5. For job in each stage, set the condition for `agent job` level: dev for dev stage, test for test stage in condition expression.

[image]

6. Run your build, it will trigger the target release, only jobs in dev stage will be executed, other jobs in test, prod stage will be skipped.

[image]

Or you can use **YAML** editor for release pipeline, which could set condition on stage level.  steps similar, details below:

1. change to trigger `build` in Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline task, as release is yaml.
2. Add variable `RunStage` and enable `Let users override this value when running this pipeline`. Release YAML as below, set condition at `stage` level:

```
trigger: none


pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
 - stage: test
  condition: eq(variables['RunStage'], 'test')
  jobs:
 - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo test 

 - stage: dev
  condition: eq(variables['RunStage'], 'dev')
  dependsOn: test
  jobs:
 - job: B1
    steps:
    - script: echo dev

 - stage: prod
  condition: eq(variables['RunStage'], 'prod')
  dependsOn: dev
  jobs:
 - job: C1
    steps:
    - script: echo dev
```

- Run the build, it will trigger the yaml release, and transfer the variable value. Only dev stage job will be executed.

[image]